# Unit Test in Swift - insert break and/or return by XCTAssertTrue-method

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I'm working the first time with Unit Tests in Swift. Later I want to start my tests by script. For that reason I prefer my own console log.

Something like this

```
print("check item \(itemToAdd) ")
XCTAssertTrue(result)
print("Checked Item \(itemToAdd) ✅")
print("Sorting works ✅")
```

But the test is always calling every line. So my output is always the same. So I tried something like this:

```
print("check item \(itemToAdd) ")
if XCTAssertTrue(result) {
//show succes code
} else {
//show details
}
```

This doesn't work. I understand why it isn't working (XCTAssertTrue has no return). But in the web I can't find a solution or an alternative.

Or is my kind of log stupid and/or not the common way? I would be happy about info. In the web I just find easy "hello world"-tests.

Comment: Typically you would not log the success like you are doing - you would only log the failure. All the XCTTest methods allow you to add an error message like this: XCTAssertTrue(false, "Failed true test")

Comment: worked for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well this is what you need:

```
print("check item \(itemToAdd) ")

if (result) {
    print("Checked Item \(itemToAdd) ✅")
    print("Sorting works ✅")
} else {
    XCTFail()
}
```